# CRM 2016 How to open an HTML window as a new window with RibbonWorkbench?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

In CRM 2016 I have a button created with the RibbonWorkbench. Whenever this is pressed, a HTML page opens. The HTML page has very limited content, so I would like it to open as a popup window, and I would like to create it with the RibbonWorkbench.

I have been Googeling away to try and find an answer for this question with no luck.

I finally managed to find a solution. So to save someone else this headache I will supply the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up the RibbonWorkbench.
2. Mark your button.
3. Choose commands. Find the command assigned to your button and fold
   it out.
4. In here you see something like "Url Command:/...".
5. Click that, look in the right side of the window under "Misc". Set
   the parameters as in the picture below.

WinParams are Javascript parameters which can be seen on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_open.asp

[image]